# RewriteRule. Get the physical port number inside the Apache configuration

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, port-number

2I have following configuration:

```
---443-> Load-Balancer-1 ---80> Apache-Proxy ---8080> Tomcat
---443-> Load-Balancer-2 ---81> Apache-Proxy ---8081> Tomcat
---443-> Load-Balancer-3 ---82> Apache-Proxy ---8082> Tomcat
```

There are several entries in the Apache server over different ports 80, 81, 81. There is a Tomcat listening port for every Apache port. Here is the simplified configuration:

```
  <VirtualHost *:80 *:81 *:82>
     RewriteRule ^/(.*) ://localhost:80<xx>/$1 [P,L]
  </VirtualHost>
```

In the configuration above instead of `<xx>` the physical apache port number must be used. In this case 80, 81 or 82.

I tried using `%{SERVER_PORT}`, but it is never a physical port. If the `UseCanonicalName Off`, it is the port of the load balancer (443 in my example). If the `UseCanonicalName On`, it is one of ports configured in the Apache configuration. In my case it always was 82.

`UseCanonicalPhysicalPort On|Off` directive was theoretically designed to solve this problem, but it seems not to be flexible enough for virtual host configuration.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#usecanonicalphysicalport

I tried to access CGI variable `SERVER_PORT` as `%{ENV:SERVER_PORT}`, but it did not exist.

I tried to workaround the problem using `SetEnvIf`, but this directive has no access to the port number at all (why?).

Current working solution was creating three different virtual host and hardcode the port number, but I do not like it.

Comment: What value does `%{HTTP_HOST}` give you? Does using `UseCanonicalPhysicalPort On` do any good?

Comment: Typo in text. Updated. Different combinations of `UseCanonicalName` and `UseCanonicalPhysicalPort` results in different ways the `SERVER_PORT` is calculated, but it was never the value I need.